# Startup HideFlashCallback Check

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

`hideFlashCallback` works well if flash is already loaded on the page and a facebook ui overlay is initiated afterwards.

However, if something like chat is already open -- then clearly no event is called.

Is there a SDK method to check if there is any facebook ui elements open? -- so I can manually hide flash on startup.

Many Thanks.